# How to pop up a full screen window in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to write a ios app that can pop up a full screen windows (e.g. to play a video) at a specify time, it seems UILocalNotification cant' help. anybody have any idea?

Comment: What did you think `UILocalNotification` was going to do...?

Answer (score 0):

You can present a `modalView` while at the same time, removing the `UIStatusBar`

Answer (score 0):

From within your view controller, you can call

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Which will display the specified view controller on top of the current one modally.

To do this on a timer interval (which is what I think you're implying you want to do?) you'd do the following:

```
-(IBAction)showModalWithDelay {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.06 target:self selector:@selector(showModal) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)showModal {
    [self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but by doing this, did the user need to keep this app in foreground?

Comment: Correct. Read this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html